# Getting SciPy quantiles to match Stata xtile function

Tags: python, scipy, stata, quantile

I've inherited some old Stata code (Stata11) that uses the `xtile` function to categorize observations in a vector by their quantiles (in this case, just the standard 5 quintiles, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100%).

I'm trying to replicate a piece of the code in Python and I am using the SciPy.stats.mstats function `mquantiles()` for the computation.

As near as I can tell from Stata documentation and searching online, the Stata `xtile` method tries to invert the empirical CDF of the data, and uses the equal-weighted average of all observations for which the CDF is flat to make the cutpoint. This seems like a very poor way to categorize quantiles, but it is what it is and I am sure there are cases where this is the right thing to do.

My question is how to make `mquantiles()` produce the same sort of breaking convention. I noticed that this function has two parameters, `alphap` and `betap` (the documentation calls them `alpha` and `beta` but you need the extra 'p' to get it to work, at least I do... I get an error if I just use 'alpha' and 'beta' with Python 2.7.1 and SciPy 0.10.0). But even in the SciPy docs, I can't see whether there's a combination of these parameters that produces the mean over flat CDF ranges.

I see what looks like the option to compute as the median or mode of this range, but not mean (it's also not clear if these SciPy median/mode options with alpha and beta are computed as the median/mode of the *observations* or of the range that would produce the flat CDF value.)

Any help disambiguating these different options and finding some documentation that helps me recreate the Stata convention in Python would be great. Please refrain from answers that just say "write your own quantile function." Firstly, that doesn't help me understand the conventions of either Stata or SciPy, and secondly, given these numerical libraries, writing my own quantile function should be a last resort. I can certainly do it, but it would be bad all around if I need to.

Comment: You'll have to implement three-four quantile examples with small data sets of 5-10 observations to see if you can match Stata's results, step-by-step. I have been rewriting SPSS quantile function in Stata, and working with toy data sets was the only way to see if my procedure worked, and delineate the set of circumstances under which it fails. Unlike Stata's documentation that is clear, at least as far as `xtile` is concerned, SPSS documentation is opaque and incomplete. I too tried to find some some pre-canned solutions and manipulate Stata options, but they would never work out as needed.

Comment: That's funny, because I think `xtile` has poor documentation, among the poorest I've ever seen (when you adjust for the fact that it costs money) in ~10 years of software development experience. I dread to think of what SPSS must be like.

Comment: Well, at least I was able to reproduce Stata steps. If you were to say now that R documentation is terrific, I will just throw my hands up in despair ;)

Comment: EMS, I don't understand what you are referring to about "poor documentation": not only is `xtile` open source (it is implemented within an ado-file), but it is extensively documented in the help with numerous examples, technical notes, and a full page of mathematical explanation in the "Methods and Formulas" section.

Comment: Take a look at the [doc page](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?xtile). Where does this explain what it does other than to say "The default method is to invert the empirical distribution function by using averages, where the function is flat (the default is the same method used by summarize; see [R] summarize)" ? And if you follow the other doc link there, it gives even less information. I don't have a Stata license. Just a text file with the code. Maybe the within-program docs are better, but the one I linked above is pretty bad and thoroughly unhelpful.

Comment: As of Stata 13 (June 2013) entire documentation for Stata is publicly accessible http://www.stata.com/manuals13/dpctile.pdf is the pertinent manual entry.

Comment: Yes, page 10 of that link does finally expand on what they say on page 9.. ("invert the empirical distribution function by using averages.."). The documentation was accessible before, jut did not explain what specific interpolation scheme was meant by "invert the empirical distribution function by using averages.." which is mathematically vague. It's also super weird that the [doc page](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?xtile) doesn't contain the mathematical description of `xtile` and a whole separate link overview of both `pctile` and `xtile` is required to find it.

Comment: No; it's not super weird at all. It's been standard for several versions of Stata that formulas have been given in the manuals and not in the help. The manuals and the help together make up the documentation. Also, the formulas have been given in the manual entry since `xtile` was introduced. The term `doc page` is alien to Stata. What you missed in 2012 was the manual entry not accessible to you because you did not have access to Stata, but Stata users did.

Comment: It's weird that Stata would have ever adopted that standard.

Comment: I record my dissent with @EMS's persistent and incorrect references to an `xtile` function in Stata. Commands and functions are both defined in Stata but are quite disjoint.  There is no `xtile` function in Stata. Stata's terminology is surely pertinent to Stata questions. Using some terminology out of personal preference or greater familiarity with other software is inappropriate.

Comment: Why were the terminology corrections reverted? It seems helpful to use Stata conventions for Stata aspects of the question.

Comment: Because the question is about a cross-language problem. Whatever Stata calls infix thingies typed like terminal commands is irrelevant. The Platonic thingy that I'm trying to refer to is the function (thing that maps args to outputs) that computes percentile bucket membership (in both Python and Stata) and getting them to match. I think it's hair-splitting to edit the post in such a trivial way and felt like sticking up for my original intent.

Comment: You get to keep your original wording as a courtesy to you as original poster, but it seems that you have convinced no-one. The  assertions about what is relevant here seem largely personal views. Cross-communication between people using different languages can't be helped by using incorrect terminology; programming is all about getting the details exactly right. There could be an `xtile` function in Stata, but there isn't one; that is a matter of fact.

Comment: Since you are refering to an entity existing in Stata, Stata's terminology is what counts. Especially, since the people who might know the answer are the ones familiar with Stata and its terminology. So it is in your interest to make this question as readable to them as possible, regardless of your preferences.

Comment: I appreciate your points of view; I disagree with them and I am not interested in trying to convince anyone about it.

Comment: @EMS From the cross-language perspective that's a good point. My Python is weak, so I don't have a Python analogy, but calling a Stata command a function gets the same response from Stata wizards (i.e., Nick and Maarten) as does calling an R package a library from R wizards. :)

Comment: @EMS - I agree that the terminology here is orthogonal to your question, which is clear and found a documentation error (not a downvoter :) ). But is this a good topic for Meta? What are the limits of precise terminology? I can see both sides, but there is an important distinction between Stata commands and functions.

Comment: I didn't downvote. The question was fair.

Comment: guys, now in 2016 do we have a way to match Stata func... err Stata xtile command in Python?? :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The scipy.stats.mquantiles documentation was poor and *wrong* in places, fixed now so that might be helpful...
http://docs.scipy.org/scipy/docs/scipy.stats.mstats_basic.mquantiles/.  That process started when you pointed out the alpha/beta, alphap/betap discrepancy. Thank you.

The implementation of mquantiles follow R.

The biggest difference comes from that R has 9 discrete types, where because scipy.stats.mquantiles calculates 'm' from 'alphap' and 'betap', scipy has a continuous range of "types" (for lack of a better word).

I admit that I do not understand all of the ins and outs of the statistics involved so I settled on a brute force evaluation.  I found an xtile example at http://www.biostat.sdu.dk/~biostat/StataReferenceManual/StataRef.pdf and was able to match the results with alphap=0.5, and betap=0.5 (piecewise linear).  Not definitive nor exhaustive, but all I have right now.

```
In [1]: import scipy.stats as st

In [9]: st.mstats.mquantiles([23,56,67,123,99,17],prob=[0.5],alphap=0.5,betap=.5)
Out[9]: array([ 61.5])

In [10]: st.mstats.mquantiles([23,56,67,123,99,17],prob=[0.33,0.66],alphap=0.5,betap=.5)
Out[10]: array([ 38.84,  81.72])

In [11]: st.mstats.mquantiles([23,56,67,123,99,17],prob=[0.25,0.5,0.75],alphap=0.5,betap=.5)
Out[11]: array([ 23. ,  61.5,  99. ])
```

The last is a little problematic since two of the division points are exactly on values in the data set.  Stata/xtile (at least in the examples that I found) does not give the split points for the quantiles but gives the quantiles themselves.  Given the sorted data set [17,23,56,67,99,123], Stata/xtile gave the categorization as [1,1,2,3,3,4] which means that for scipy.stat.mquantiles to match the upper bound of a quantile is greater than or equal to all values in that quantile.

Comment: hey mr. F, so have you been able to match Stata's function? ;-)