# how to compute quantile bins in Pandas when there are ties in the data?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics, stata

Consider the following simple example. I am interested in getting a categorical variable that contains categories corresponding to quantiles.

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'A':'foo foo foo bar bar bar'.split(),
                       'B':[0, 0, 1]*2})

df
Out[67]: 
     A  B
0  foo  0
1  foo  0
2  foo  1
3  bar  0
4  bar  0
5  bar  1
```

In Pandas, `qtile` does the job. Unfortunately, `qtile` will fail here because of the ties in the data.

```
df['C'] = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].transform(
                     lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 3, labels=range(1,4)))
```

gives the classic `ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.33333333,  1.        ])`

Is there another robust solution (from any other python package) that does not require to reinvent the wheel?

It has to be. I dont want to code myself my own quantile bin function. Any decent stats package can handle ties when creating quantile bins (`SAS`, `Stata`, etc).

I want to have something that is based on sound methodological choices and robust.

For instance, look here for a solution in SAS https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146840.htm.

Or here for the well known xtile in Stata (http://www.stata.com/manuals13/dpctile.pdf). Note this SO post [Definitive way to match Stata weighted xtile command using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585564/definitive-way-to-match-stata-weighted-xtile-command-using-python)

What am I missing? Maybe using `Scipy`?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`numpy.digitize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html)

```
df['C'] = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].transform(lambda x: np.digitize(x,bins=np.array([0,1,2])))

     A  B  C
0  foo  0  1
1  foo  0  1
2  foo  1  2
3  bar  0  1
4  bar  0  1
5  bar  1  2
```

Comment: thanks @NickilMaveli but it seems `numpy.digitize` does not create quantile bins, but rather linearly spaced bins

Comment: In that case you can pass the output of `pd.quantile()` method to `np.digitize` function. If non-unique values are present, then it would assign the integer associated with the last quartile(here, 3).

Comment: very nice suggestion indeed. unfortunately, I think putting them to the minimum quartile is more common.. maybe there is another solution out there..